# Recursive mkdir() system call on Unix

Tags: c, posix, unix, mkdir

After reading the mkdir(2) man page for the Unix system call with that name, it appears that the call doesn't create intermediate directories in a path, only the last directory in the path. Is there any way (or other function) to create all the directories in the path without resorting to manually parsing my directory string and individually creating each directory ?

Comment: Please don't add any more implementations of this function as answers.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

There is not a system call to do it for you, unfortunately.  I'm guessing that's because there isn't a way to have really well-defined semantics for what should happen in error cases.  Should it leave the directories that have already been created?  Delete them?  What if the deletions fail? And so on...

It is pretty easy to roll your own, however, and a quick google for '[recursive mkdir](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&q=recursive+mkdir&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=)' turned up a number of solutions.  Here's one that was near the top:

http://nion.modprobe.de/blog/archives/357-Recursive-directory-creation.html

```
static void _mkdir(const char *dir) {
    char tmp[256];
    char *p = NULL;
    size_t len;

    snprintf(tmp, sizeof(tmp),"%s",dir);
    len = strlen(tmp);
    if (tmp[len - 1] == '/')
        tmp[len - 1] = 0;
    for (p = tmp + 1; *p; p++)
        if (*p == '/') {
            *p = 0;
            mkdir(tmp, S_IRWXU);
            *p = '/';
        }
    mkdir(tmp, S_IRWXU);
}
```

Comment: The only thing I would change is tmp[256] to tmp[PATH_MAX]
also #include <limits.h>

Comment: Improved version: https://gist.github.com/JonathonReinhart/8c0d90191c38af2dcadb102c4e202950

Comment: `snprintf()` returns the length of the string formatted, the call to `strlen()` is superfluous. `len = snprintf(tmp, ... `. You can check for buffer overflow that way `if(len >= sizeof tmp)`. With the `strlen()` it's not possible.

Comment: What if mkdir in loop failed to create a directory? For instance of permissions? I would strongly recommend mentioned version from github https://gist.github.com/JonathonReinhart/8c0d90191c38af2dcadb102c4e202950

Comment: @rouzier `PATH_MAX` may not be an improvement as `PATH_MAX` will not be defined on [POSIX-compliant systems where the value varies between different file systems](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html#tag_13_23_03_02) (bolding mine): "A definition of one of the symbolic constants in the following list **shall be omitted** from the `<limits.h>` header on specific implementations where the corresponding value is equal to or greater than the stated minimum, but where the value can vary depending on the file to which it is applied."

Answer (score 69):

hmm I thought that mkdir -p does that?

> mkdir -p this/is/a/full/path/of/stuff

Comment: Yes it does, but the question pertains to a C function call.

Comment: Indeed - the upvotes presumably reflect that this has been a useful answer for many, **but it is an answer to a different question than the one which was asked**.

Comment: One could however have a look at the source code for mkdir to see how *it* does it. Doing a quick google, it seems the relevant code is in [mkancestdirs.c](https://fossies.org/dox/coreutils-8.23/mkancesdirs_8c_source.html) in `coreutils`

Comment: This is an answer for different question asked.

Comment: @gamen, The link in your comment is stale.

Comment: @merlin2011 thanks for noticing. The latest equivalent URL (for coreutils 8.26) is: https://fossies.org/dox/coreutils-8.26/mkancesdirs_8c_source.html. Reflecting on past criticisms of this suggested answer, I agree. It should rather have been a comment to the question.

Comment: @CraigMcQueen Sure. `system("mkdir -p this/is/a/full/path/of/stuff");`

Comment: @JasonC Perhaps, though using `system("mkdir -p ...")` is risky if the directory name is user input; then the user input requires careful sanitisation/validation. [C system() function vulnerability - Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/c-system-function-vulnerability)

Comment: @CraigMcQueen Truth. Then: `!fork() && execlp("mkdir", "mkdir", "-p", pathname, NULL)`.

Answer (score 30):

Here is my solution. By calling the function below you ensure that all dirs leading to the file path specified exist. Note that `file_path` argument is not directory name here but rather a path to a file that you are going to create after calling `mkpath()`.

Eg., `mkpath("/home/me/dir/subdir/file.dat", 0755)` shall create `/home/me/dir/subdir` if it does not exist. `mkpath("/home/me/dir/subdir/", 0755)` does the same.

Works with relative paths as well.

Returns `-1` and sets `errno` in case of an error.

```
int mkpath(char* file_path, mode_t mode) {
    assert(file_path && *file_path);
    for (char* p = strchr(file_path + 1, '/'); p; p = strchr(p + 1, '/')) {
        *p = '\0';
        if (mkdir(file_path, mode) == -1) {
            if (errno != EEXIST) {
                *p = '/';
                return -1;
            }
        }
        *p = '/';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `file_path` is modified during the action but gets restored afterwards. Therefore `file_path` is not strictly `const`.

Comment: better than the accepted answer; with error handling!

Comment: The only problem is that it uses a non-const `char *` as parameter because it changes the contents of the original pointer. This is not ideal since it wont work with static const strings, for example, and it has an unnecessary API requirement.

Comment: @FelipeTonello You can easily allocate memory and make a copy of the parameter as suggested in other answers. My goal was performance so I tried to avoid expensive operations such as memory allocation.

Answer (score 14):

Here's another take on `mkpath()`, using recursion, which is both small and readable.  It makes use of `strdupa()` to avoid altering the given `dir` string argument directly and to avoid using `malloc()` & `free()`.  Make sure to compile with `-D_GNU_SOURCE` to activate `strdupa()` ... meaning this code only works on GLIBC, EGLIBC, uClibc, and other GLIBC compatible C libraries.

```
int mkpath(char *dir, mode_t mode)
{
    if (!dir) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return 1;
    }

    if (strlen(dir) == 1 && dir[0] == '/')
        return 0;

    mkpath(dirname(strdupa(dir)), mode);

    return mkdir(dir, mode);
}
```

After input both here and from Valery Frolov, in the Inadyn project, the following revised version of `mkpath()` has now been pushed to [libite](https://www.github.com/troglobit/libite)

```
int mkpath(char *dir, mode_t mode)
{
    struct stat sb;

    if (!dir) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return 1;
    }

    if (!stat(dir, &sb))
        return 0;

    mkpath(dirname(strdupa(dir)), mode);

    return mkdir(dir, mode);
}
```

It uses one more syscall, but otoh the code is more readable now.

Comment: Wouldn't this leak memory every time `strdupa` is called?

Comment: Nope :)

When the function goes out of context the memory allocated (on the stack) by `strdupa()` is freed automatically.  See the man page for more details.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're right. I thought of `strdup` all the time. :)

Comment: I know this is a very old thread, but I was looking for a solution to  this  and I liked this answer the best out of everything I've seen. HOWEVER, this does not work with a relative path. Adding a check for dir[0] == '.'  to the check for dir[0]=='/' would correct this as that is what dirname ends up with.

Comment: This still isn't ideal as it tries to create the ".." folder, but that just returns a file exists error and keeps going. You could also do a mkdir first, and only recurse if mkdir returns ENOENT. Downside to that is you would have to call mkdir twice in the method.

Comment: Thanks, my personal use-case didn't trigger that.  Got input on this relative path problem also in the Inadyn project.  See revised code above.

Comment: Very elegant solution! I ran it under `valgrind` and indeed it confirms there is no leak memory but the man page states the memory has to be released calling `free`: [http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdupa](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdupa). How ever, adding the `#include` statements would make it a bit easier to test it... :-)

Comment: @AlBundy check the man page again, the statement regarding `free()` is for `strdup()`, not `strdupa()`.

Comment: De verdad! Mea culpa muchisomo! I implemented it as a lambda function and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at the bash source code [here](ftp://ftp.cwru.edu/pub/bash/bash-4.1.tar.gz), and specifically look in examples/loadables/mkdir.c especially lines 136-210. If you don't want to do that, here's some of the source that deals with this (taken straight from the tar.gz that I've linked):

```
/* Make all the directories leading up to PATH, then create PATH.  Note that
   this changes the process's umask; make sure that all paths leading to a
   return reset it to ORIGINAL_UMASK */

static int
make_path (path, nmode, parent_mode)
     char *path;
     int nmode, parent_mode;
{
  int oumask;
  struct stat sb;
  char *p, *npath;

  if (stat (path, &sb) == 0)
  {
      if (S_ISDIR (sb.st_mode) == 0)
      {
          builtin_error ("`%s': file exists but is not a directory", path);
          return 1;
      }

      if (chmod (path, nmode))
      {
          builtin_error ("%s: %s", path, strerror (errno));
          return 1;
      }

      return 0;
  }

  oumask = umask (0);
  npath = savestring (path);    /* So we can write to it. */

  /* Check whether or not we need to do anything with intermediate dirs. */

  /* Skip leading slashes. */
  p = npath;
  while (*p == '/')
    p++;

  while (p = strchr (p, '/'))
  {
      *p = '\0';
      if (stat (npath, &sb) != 0)
      {
          if (mkdir (npath, parent_mode))
          {
              builtin_error ("cannot create directory `%s': %s", npath, strerror (errno));
              umask (original_umask);
              free (npath);
              return 1;
          }
      }
      else if (S_ISDIR (sb.st_mode) == 0)
      {
          builtin_error ("`%s': file exists but is not a directory", npath);
          umask (original_umask);
          free (npath);
          return 1;
      }

      *p++ = '/';   /* restore slash */
      while (*p == '/')
          p++;
  }

  /* Create the final directory component. */
  if (stat (npath, &sb) && mkdir (npath, nmode))
  {
      builtin_error ("cannot create directory `%s': %s", npath, strerror (errno));
      umask (original_umask);
      free (npath);
      return 1;
  }

  umask (original_umask);
  free (npath);
  return 0;
}
```

You can probably get away with a less general implementation.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently not, my two suggestions are:

```
char dirpath[80] = "/path/to/some/directory";
sprintf(mkcmd, "mkdir -p %s", dirpath);
system(mkcmd);
```

Or if you don't want to use `system()` try looking at the coreutils `mkdir` source code and see how they implemented the `-p` option.

Comment: I pretty much can't use the system command because I'm using a severely impaired (even for busybox) version of busybox.  I can't assume that any command has all the standard arguments, or is even installed for that matter, because I'm working on an embedded system.  I went with Carl Norum's answer because it works the best in my specific scenario, but your answer was good as well.

Comment: OMG - it's 2014, file paths have usually spaces now. 
Please don't code like this

Comment: @Lothar Perhaps you didn't realize that this answer was made more than 4 years ago, so `OMG - it's 2010` would be more apt.  Perhaps it's just me, but a lack of quotes around `%s` hardly seems appropriate to bring a deity into the mix.  If you'd like to suggest the edit, please feel free to do so.

Comment: @Lothar There's also the bad choice to use system() for this in the first place, the security flaw from not using an absolute path to mkdir, and the incorrectly coded 'char dirpath[]' line; every line has something wrong with it so had to downvote it; sorry SiegeX, but this was a really bad answer, but as you said, it was in 2010 ;)

Comment: @Nick I can see a security flaw if I was passing a user-provided path to `system()`, but I am not, the path is hard coded so other than portable limitations, I don't see the issue.  Also, what was "incorrectly coded" in the `char dirpath[]` line, the extra 56 bytes allocated on the stack?

Comment: /bin/sh will use the PATH environment variable to locate mkdir. If an executable called mkdir is in a path location before /bin, that will be executed instead.

Comment: Oops buffer overflow. And you better hope no-one creates a path ending in ;rm -rf ~

Comment: Wow that's a lot of completely non-constructive comments. The issues raised can be avoided with e.g. `!fork() && execlp("mkdir", "mkdir", "-p", dirpath, NULL)` instead. Same idea. With `system`, though -- buffer safety: `asprintf` or `snprintf_s`, space support: you'll have to escape quotes then use `\"%s\"`, sanitization: non-trivial which is kind of a dealbreaker.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not allowed to comment on the first (and accepted) answer (not enough rep), so I'll post my comments as code in a new answer. The code below is based on the first answer, but fixes a number of problems:

- If called with a zero-length path, this does not read or write the character before the beginning of array `opath[]` (yes, "why would you call it that way?", but on the other hand "why would you not fix the vulnerability?")
- the size of `opath` is now `PATH_MAX` (which isn't perfect, but is better than a constant)
- if the path is as long as or longer than `sizeof(opath)` then it is properly terminated when copied (which `strncpy()` doesn't do)
- you can specify the mode of the written directory, just as you can with the standard `mkdir()` (although if you specify non-user-writeable or non-user-executable then the recursion won't work)
- main() returns the (required?) int
- removed a few unnecessary `#include`s
- I like the function name better ;)

```
// Based on http://nion.modprobe.de/blog/archives/357-Recursive-directory-creation.html
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>

static void mkdirRecursive(const char *path, mode_t mode) {
    char opath[PATH_MAX];
    char *p;
    size_t len;

    strncpy(opath, path, sizeof(opath));
    opath[sizeof(opath) - 1] = '\0';
    len = strlen(opath);
    if (len == 0)
        return;
    else if (opath[len - 1] == '/')
        opath[len - 1] = '\0';
    for(p = opath; *p; p++)
        if (*p == '/') {
            *p = '\0';
            if (access(opath, F_OK))
                mkdir(opath, mode);
            *p = '/';
        }
    if (access(opath, F_OK))         /* if path is not terminated with / */
        mkdir(opath, mode);
}


int main (void) {
    mkdirRecursive("/Users/griscom/one/two/three", S_IRWXU);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would change this to return int. so its just a 1 word change to refactor.

Answer (score 1):

My recursive way of doing this:

```
#include <libgen.h> /* Only POSIX version of dirname() */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void recursive_mkdir(const char *path, mode_t mode)
{
    char *spath = NULL;
    const char *next_dir = NULL;

    /* dirname() modifies input! */
    spath = strdup(path);
    if (spath == NULL)
    {
        /* Report error, no memory left for string duplicate. */
        goto done;
    }

    /* Get next path component: */
    next_dir = dirname(spath);

    if (access(path, F_OK) == 0)
    {
        /* The directory in question already exists! */
        goto done;
    }

    if (strcmp(next_dir, ".") == 0 || strcmp(next_dir, "/") == 0)
    {
        /* We reached the end of recursion! */
        goto done;
    }

    recursive_mkdir(next_dir, mode);
    if (mkdir(path, mode) != 0)
    {
       /* Report error on creating directory */
    }

done:
    free(spath);
    return;
}
```

EDIT: fixed my old code snippet, bug-report by [Namchester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3195349/namchester)

Comment: @Jeff, Yup. Any problem with that? In this case looks easier to understand than plenty of ifs or something like that. It's readable and works well.

Comment: Doesn't create the last directory. If recursive_mkdir("/home/test/hello",mode), doesn't create hello directory.

Comment: @Namchester, apparently it does not work that well with absolute paths. Fixing.

Answer (score 1):

Simply works without recursion

```c
int mkdir_p(const char *path, int mode)
{
    char *buf = strdup(path);
    char *p = buf;
    int ret = 0;

    if (buf == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    mode |= 0700;

    do {
        p = strchr(p + 1, '/');
        if (p) {
            *p = '\0';
        }
        if (mkdir(buf, mode) != 0) {
            if (errno != EEXIST) {
                ret = errno;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (p) {
            *p = '/';
        }
    } while (p);

    free(buf);

    return (ret);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    mkdir_p("/home/swei/data_xx/algo/trade/session/1", 0666);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two other answers given are for `mkdir(1)` and not `mkdir(2)` like you ask for, but you can look at [the source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/mkdir.c) for that program and see how it implements the `-p` options which calls `mkdir(2)` repeatedly as needed.

Comment: The actual question was "Is there any way (or other function) to create all the directories in the path without resorting to manually parsing my directory string and individually creating each directory " so mkdir(1) is another way!

Comment: The `make_dir_parents()` function is probably the most interesting bit, but it's not in that file. It is in [`mkdir-p.c` in the gnulib repository](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/mkdir-p.c#n85).

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
int mkrdir(const char *path, int index, int permission)
{
    char bf[NAME_MAX];
    if(*path == '/')
        index++;
    char *p = strchr(path + index, '/');
    int len;
    if(p) {
        len = MIN(p-path, sizeof(bf)-1);
        strncpy(bf, path, len);
        bf[len]=0;
    } else {
        len = MIN(strlen(path)+1, sizeof(bf)-1);
        strncpy(bf, path, len);
        bf[len]=0;
    }

    if(access(bf, 0)!=0) {
        mkdir(bf, permission);
        if(access(bf, 0)!=0) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    if(p) {
        return mkrdir(path, p-path+1, permission);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my shot at a more general solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

typedef int (*dirhandler_t)( const char*, void* );
/// calls itfunc for each directory in path (except for . and ..)
int iterate_path( const char* path, dirhandler_t itfunc, void* udata )
{
    int rv = 0;
    char tmp[ 256 ];
    char *p = tmp;
    char *lp = tmp;
    size_t len;
    size_t sublen;
    int ignore_entry;

    strncpy( tmp, path, 255 );

    tmp[ 255 ] = '\0';
    len = strlen( tmp );

    if( 0 == len ||
        (1 == len && '/' == tmp[ 0 ]) )
        return 0;

    if( tmp[ len - 1 ] == '/' )
        tmp[ len - 1 ] = 0;

    while( (p = strchr( p, '/' )) != NULL )
    {
        ignore_entry = 0;
        *p = '\0';
        lp = strrchr( tmp, '/' );

        if( NULL == lp ) { lp = tmp; }
        else { lp++; }

        sublen = strlen( lp );

        if( 0 == sublen )   /* ignore things like '//' */
            ignore_entry = 1;
        else if( 1 == sublen &&  /* ignore things like '/./' */
                 '.' == lp[ 0 ] )
            ignore_entry = 1;
        else if( 2 == sublen &&    /* also ignore things like '/../' */
                 '.' == lp[ 0 ] &&
                 '.' == lp[ 1 ] )
            ignore_entry = 1;

        if( ! ignore_entry )
        {
            if( (rv = itfunc( tmp, udata )) != 0 )
                return rv;
        }

        *p = '/';
        p++;
        lp = p;
    }

    if( strcmp( lp, "." ) && strcmp( lp, ".." ) )
        return itfunc( tmp, udata );

    return 0;
}

mode_t get_file_mode( const char* path )
{
    struct stat statbuf;
    memset( &statbuf, 0, sizeof( statbuf ) );

    if( NULL == path ) { return 0; }

    if( 0 != stat( path, &statbuf ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "failed to stat '%s': %s\n",
                 path, strerror( errno ) );
        return 0;
    }

    return statbuf.st_mode;
}

static int mymkdir( const char* path, void* udata )
{
    (void)udata;
    int rv = mkdir( path, S_IRWXU );
    int errnum = errno;

    if( 0 != rv )
    {
        if( EEXIST == errno &&
            S_ISDIR( get_file_mode( path ) ) )  /* it's all good, the directory already exists */
            return 0;

        fprintf( stderr, "mkdir( %s ) failed: %s\n",
                 path, strerror( errnum ) );
    }
//     else
//     {
//         fprintf( stderr, "created directory: %s\n", path );
//     }

    return rv;
}

int mkdir_with_leading( const char* path )
{
    return iterate_path( path, mymkdir, NULL );
}

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    size_t i;
    int rv;

    if( argc < 2 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "usage: %s <path> [<path>...]\n",
                 argv[ 0 ] );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    for( i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
    {
        rv = mkdir_with_leading( argv[ i ] );
        if( 0 != rv )
            return rv;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like recursion because it's fun!

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> /* mkdir(2) */
#include <limits.h> /* PATH_MAX */    
int mkdirp(const char *dir, const mode_t mode){
        struct stat sb;
        //if dir already exists and is a directory
        if (stat(dir, &sb) == 0){
            if (S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)) {
                return 0;
            }
            else return -1;
        }
        else {
            char tmp[PATH_MAX];
            size_t len = strnlen(dir, PATH_MAX);
            memcpy(tmp, dir, len);
            //remove trailing slash
            if (tmp[len-1]=='/'){
                tmp[len-1]='\0';
            }
            char *p = strrchr(tmp, '/');
            *p='\0';
            int ret = mkdirp(tmp, mode);
            if (ret == 0){
                return mkdir(dir, mode);
            }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A very simple solution, just pass in input: `mkdir dirname`

```
void execute_command_mkdir(char *input)
{
     char rec_dir[500];
     int s;
     if(strcmp(input,"mkdir") == 0)
        printf("mkdir: operand required");
    else
     {
        char *split = strtok(input," \t");
        while(split)
        {
            if(strcmp(split,"create_dir") != 0)
                strcpy(rec_dir,split);
            split = strtok(NULL, " \t");
        }
        char *split2 = strtok(rec_dir,"/");
        char dir[500];
        strcpy(dir, "");
        while(split2)
        {
            strcat(dir,split2);
            strcat(dir,"/");
            printf("%s %s\n",split2,dir);
            s = mkdir(dir,0700);
            split2 = strtok(NULL,"/");
        }
        strcpy(output,"ok");
    }
        if(s < 0)
            printf(output,"Error!! Cannot Create Directory!!");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Quite straight. This can be a good starting point

```
int makeDir(char *fullpath, mode_t permissions){
int i=0;
char *arrDirs[20];
char aggrpaz[255];
arrDirs[i] = strtok(fullpath,"/");
strcpy(aggrpaz, "/");
while(arrDirs[i]!=NULL)
{
    arrDirs[++i] = strtok(NULL,"/");
    strcat(aggrpaz, arrDirs[i-1]);
    mkdir(aggrpaz,permissions);
    strcat(aggrpaz, "/");
}
i=0;
return 0;
}
```

You parse this function a full path plus the permissions you want, i.e **S_IRUSR**, for a full list of modes go here https://techoverflow.net/2013/04/05/how-to-use-mkdir-from-sysstat-h/

The fullpath string will be split by the "/" character and individual dirs will be appended to the **aggrpaz** string one at a time. Each loop iteration calls the mkdir function, passing it the aggregate path so far plus the permissions. This example can be improved, I am not checking the mkdir function output and this function only works with absolute paths.

Answer (score -1):

here is my solution

```
void mkpath(char *p) {
    char *path = strdup(p);
    char  *save_path = path;
    char *sep1;
    char *sep2=0;
    do {
        int idx = (sep2-path)<0 ? 0 : sep2-path;
        sep1 = strchr(path + idx , '/');    
        sep2 = strchr(sep1+1, '/');
        if (sep2) {
            path[sep2-path]=0;
        }
        if(mkdir(path, 0777) && errno != EEXIST)
            break;
        if (sep2) {
            path[sep2-path]='/';
        }
    } while (sep2);

    free(save_path);

}

.
.
.
mkpath ("./the/new/path")
```

Comment: There are 14 other answers on this decade-old question. What does your answer provide that none of the others do not?