# In C, how can I create a file from a filepath, even if the directories are not existing?

Tags: c, unix, directory

I am taking a file path from a user. I need to then access that file, and create it if it does not exist. I also need to create any intermediate directories if they don't exist as well.

For example, if my directory looks like:

```
mydir
|
+---subdir
|   |
|   +-- FileA
|
+---File1
```

I might receive mydir/subdir/FileA and would then access the relevant file. However, I might also receive mydir/NewDir/FileB.

How can I do this using Unix system calls in C? I have tried using open() with the (O_RDWR | O_CREAT) flags, but this didn't work out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursive mkdir() system call on Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336242/recursive-mkdir-system-call-on-unix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed to use it, OS calls can be wrapped inside `system()` call. e.g. for listing files `system( "ls" );`

To create a directory including the intermediate ones, use `mkdir` with `-p`

```
mkdir -p mydir/NewDir/
```

(AFAIK, it doesn't hurt if NewDir already existed.)

To create an empty file, use `touch`

```
touch mydir/NewDir/FileB
```

---

**Followup**: I wrote this quick proof-of-concept program and tested in cygwin.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char const * dir = "dir/subdir";
    char const * file = "file";

    char mkdirCmd[ 80 ] = { 0 };
    strcat( mkdirCmd, "mkdir -p " );
    strcat( mkdirCmd, dir );

    char touchCmd[ 80 ] = { 0 };
    strcat( touchCmd, "touch " );
    strcat( touchCmd, dir );
    strcat( touchCmd, "/" );
    strcat( touchCmd, file );

    system( mkdirCmd );
    system( touchCmd );

    return 0;
}
```

Unit test:

```
$ ls
mkdir.c  mkdir.exe*

$ ./mkdir.exe 

$ ls
dir/  mkdir.c  mkdir.exe*

$ ls -R dir
dir:
subdir/

dir/subdir:
file
```

Comment: @dmckee: I didn't know that, always found it available in the systems I have worked, linux, solaris, cygwin. It's listed in the opengroup spec: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mkdir.html

Comment: Uh....ah...er...I wish to amend that statement. The `-p` flag as not universally available in the past, and may not exist on older installations. Yeah that's it. I would swear that I worked on such a system within the last couple of years, but can't for the life of me figure out which it was.

Comment: @dmckee: Ah, I see; good that *now* it's available on most systems.

Answer (score 3):

I think this answer covers your question:

[Recursive mkdir() system call on Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336242/recursive-mkdir-system-call-on-unix)

In short, you must create the subdirs yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no recursive 'makedir' so I'm scared that you might have to do it yourself.

But I think its gonna be easy doing it

function recursiveCreate(filepath)
   split the filepath by slash
     if last part create file
     else create directory
end

Now you have your function :) using it will make you happier than using some UNIX defined function :)