# mkdir -p equivalent in C that creates nested directories recursively

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, filesystems, mkdir

I want to create a new directory inside a new directory. Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    const char * path = "/home/abc/testabc1/testabc2" ;
    mode_t mode = 0777;

    if (mkdir(path, mode) == -1) {

//        printf("Error occurred : %s ", strerror(errno));
        perror("abc");

    }

    else {

        printf("Directory created\n");
    }


}
```

When I do this I get this error:

```
abc: No such file or directory
```

If I remove testabc2 then I am able to create the directory with success. Why so ?

Comment: what is the permission & ownership of created `testabc2`? which user do you run the program ?

Comment: Running as non root user. I am specifying mode as 0777. Its in the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursive mkdir() system call on Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336242/recursive-mkdir-system-call-on-unix)

Comment: does the directory `testabc1` exist ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz No it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only create directories in existing directories. If you want to do the equivalent of `mkdir -p` you have to do the same thing it does, namely create one directory after another from the top of the path down.

In your case, that means `mkdir` of `/home/abc/testabc1` before `mkdir` of `/home/abc/testabc1/testabc2`.

Your error message is also misleading since `perror("abc");` will prepend *any* error with "abc:". It has nothing to do with the directory "abc".