# how to create folders using mkdir in c?

Tags: c, mkdir

I'm trying to create a folder using mkdir in C but it wont't work

the code won't create the folders

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){
    char chemin[256];
    char name[20];
    //char fichier[100];                                                        
//  FILE *fp;                                                                   
    strcpy(chemin,"/home/Deva/Documents/prog/C/la/sds");

    mkdir(chemin,0755);
    if (mkdir(chemin,0755)==-1){
        printf("\nERROR\n");
    } else { printf("fichier creer"); }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a new directory in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430248/creating-a-new-directory-in-c)

Comment: You are actually calling the "mkdir" function twice.  Did you look to see if the directory is there after running your code?  It may be failing the second time because it already exists.  If that's not the problem, take a look at the "perror" which should give you more info about the error you're running into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing PATH not just directory name.
so please check below post would help

[Recursive mkdir() system call on Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336242/recursive-mkdir-system-call-on-unix)

Answer (score 3):

You have to create the intermediate directories first: e.g. you must create /home/Deva before creating /home/Deva/Documents, etc.

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

1) You need to create the intermediate directories first.

2) You cannot create a directory twice, which you do here:

```
mkdir(chemin,0755);
if (mkdir(chemin,0755)==-1){
```

Comment: yup, `if(chemin, 0755) {...}` will do perfectly

Comment: @JennyT-Type Say what? That would always return true no matter what.

Comment: @oops, I meant `if(mkdir(chemin, 0755) == -1){...}` that was me *not* copy/pasting when I should have. should I delete the first attempt? I mean to not spread misinformation,